# Why successListener is called even if element is not inserted into an array in Firestore document?

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use the following code to add userId to an array in a Cloud Firestore document:

```
DocumentReference reference = firebaseFirestore.collection("photos").document(photoId);
reference.update("views", FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.getUid()))
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
            {
                reference.update("viewsCount", FieldValue.increment(1));
            }
        });
```

As you can see from the code, I want the `viewsCount` to increment only if element is added to the `views` array.

According to this [Adding Data](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/add-data) document, **`arrayUnion()` adds elements to an array but only elements not already present**, and thats exactly what I wanted.

But, the problem is that when I add an already present element into the array, the element is not inserted, but **`addOnSuccessListener` is called, `viewsCount` is incremented and failureListener is never called.** Is there any way to prevent this? I want the `viewsCount`to be incremented only when an element is inserted into `views` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, the problem is that when I add an already present element into the array, the element is not inserted, but `addOnSuccessListener` is called, viewsCount is incremented and `failureListener` is never called.

That's the normal behaviour. Please note that the `OnSuccessListener` that you are currently using is called for an operation that you have performed in the database only if the final result of that particular operation succeeded.

In your particular case:

```
.update("views", FieldValue.arrayUnion(currentUser.getUid())
```

The `OnSuccessListener` is called after the operation that is adding the `uid` to your `views` array succeeded. It doesn't really matter if that `uid` was already there or not, the entire operation succeeded. It's true that the `uid` was not added to the array but even though, the operation was successful.

Please also rememeber, that a Task is considered successful when the work represented by the Task is finished, as expected, with no errors. On the other hand, `OnFailureListener` is called when a Task fails with an exception. So it can be a result or an Exception, never both. So adding an `uid` that already exsists in an array can never be cosidered a failure.

To solve this, you should create a `get()` call, get the entire document and check the existnce of the `uid` in `views` array. If it doesn't exist, create the update and increment the counter, otherwise take no action.

Comment: K.. I thought failure to add element to array will not call successListener. Thanks for ur answer.